# Need to uninstall Nouveau on Fedora 23 but can't find a good guide

Tags: fedora, uninstall, nouveau

I'm having the same issue as [this guy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251629/how-to-install-nvidia-proprietary-drivers-on-fedora-23/252122#252122?newreg=7745cd7f7a974d39b718c0257b5c014b) except I have an older laptop running an Nvidia Quadro NVS 160M and RPMFusion is useless for such an old device.

I have the driver I need. I know how to install it properly. However, when I go to install it, I get the error message that Nouveau is installed and it has to be removed before I can install my driver. It attempts to blacklist Nouveau, but fails.

I've also run through several tutorials online about how to blacklist Nouveau and none of them worked.

Does anyone know how to remove all traces of Nouveau? I have wheel access and can run it as init 3 if necessary. Any ideas how to nuke nouveau out of my system?

This process was much simpler on older versions of Ubuntu I could specify the graphics driver via a gui. I'm completely at a loss how to get rid of Nouveau on Fedora as this is my first time using it.

Comment: Yes, I know that there can be consequences for completely uninstalling Nouveau, but I already have the driver I need. I can INIT 3 then do the uninstall and reinstall. I just can't seem to find a tutorial to cleanly uninstall nouveau.

Comment: I might have found the answer but I won't know for sure until I try it. It looks like nouveau driver is registered in initrd and is loaded at boot time. regenerating initrd by using 'dracut -f' is supposed to work after it's been completely blacklisted and dnf removed. If that works, I'll post it. [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3lmzy1/i_need_help_all_disabling_nouveau_and_using/)

Comment: And if it doesn't work, try updating your question with what you did and the results. Oh, and Welcome!

Comment: You are almost certainly not installing the nvidia driver properly, there is no need to remove Nouveau at all. See http://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia